# How does the python port of libsvm's predict_proba work?

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, libsvm

I've followed through the original libsvm code on it's [github][1].
I'm not concerned about the theoretical backfground of how the probability estimates are derived.
All that I care about is how to predict the probabilities from the trained model.

I know that there's the method `svm.SVC.predict_proba` but it seems that it doesn't work exactly as the original function in libsvm called `svm_predict_probability`.

For a two-class classification problem, the latter one computes the decision values in a first step, which are then passed to a function called sigmoid_predict:

```
static double sigmoid_predict(double decision_value, double A, double B)
{
    double fApB = decision_value*A+B;
    // 1-p used later; avoid catastrophic cancellation
    if (fApB >= 0)
        return exp(-fApB)/(1.0+exp(-fApB));
    else
        return 1.0/(1+exp(fApB)) ;
}
```

I've tried to replicate these 2 steps in python.
Here's a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

X_train = np.array([[ 22.    ,   7.25  ,   2.    ,   1.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 38.    ,  71.2833,   0.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 26.    ,   7.925 ,   2.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 35.    ,  53.1   ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 35.    ,   8.05  ,   2.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 27.    ,   8.4583,   2.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 54.    ,  51.8625,   0.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [  2.    ,  21.075 ,   2.    ,   1.    ,   3.    ,   1.    ],
       [ 27.    ,  11.1333,   2.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   2.    ],
       [ 14.    ,  30.0708,   1.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ],
       [  4.    ,  16.7   ,   2.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   1.    ],
       [ 58.    ,  26.55  ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 20.    ,   8.05  ,   2.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 39.    ,  31.275 ,   2.    ,   1.    ,   1.    ,   5.    ],
       [ 14.    ,   7.8542,   2.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 55.    ,  16.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [  2.    ,  29.125 ,   2.    ,   1.    ,   4.    ,   1.    ],
       [ 23.    ,  13.    ,   1.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 31.    ,  18.    ,   2.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 22.    ,   7.225 ,   2.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 35.    ,  26.    ,   1.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 34.    ,  13.    ,   1.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 15.    ,   8.0292,   2.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 28.    ,  35.5   ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [  8.    ,  21.075 ,   2.    ,   0.    ,   3.    ,   1.    ],
       [ 38.    ,  31.3875,   2.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   5.    ],
       [ 26.    ,   7.225 ,   2.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 19.    , 263.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   3.    ,   2.    ],
       [ 24.    ,   7.8792,   2.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ],
       [ 23.    ,   7.8958,   2.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ]])

y_train =  np.array([0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.,
       1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.])

X_test = np.array([40.    , 27.7208,  0.    ,  1.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ]).reshape(1,-1)

clf = svm.SVC(gamma='scale', C=30,probability=True, random_state=0,
              kernel='poly',decision_function_shape='ovo')

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

The last command gives me `array([[0.48383569, 0.51616431]])`

Naively I would expect the following to give me the same result:

```
def sigmoid_predict(dec_val, A,B):
    fApB = dec_val*A+B
    if fApB >=0:
        return np.exp(-fApB)/(1.0+np.exp(-fApB))
    else:
        return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(fApB))

sigmoid_predict(clf.decision_function(X_test), clf.probA_,clf.probB_)
```

However, in this case the result is `array([0.48625056])` which is different from the above one.
Im not talking about the fact, that this a 1x1 array instead of a 2x1-arrays. That's fine. But the values don't match. In this specific example its just a minor difference but for other test-data it becomes quite large. So this is definitely not due to some roundoff error.

What is happening? Are there some steps I'm missing? I've gone through all the C-Code and couldn't figure out what's missing there. Are there some additional steps in the python port of libsvm, maybe some kind of internal scaling?

Any advice?

EDIT: I just found that
clf._dense_decision_function(X_test) = -clf.decision_function(X_test)

and

```
sigmoid_predict(clf._dense_decision_function(X_test), clf.probA_,clf.probB_)
```

gives very similar results to `clf.predict_proba(...)` (I suppose the slight difference may be attributed to a conversion from float to double when using clf.predict_proba(...))

Still I have no clue why...
But it's good enough for now..
[1]: https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp

Comment: You are calculating probabilities for one class, wile the `predict_proba` gives you probabilities for both. 1 - 0.48625056 = 0.51616431

Comment: In this 2-class classification problem it doesn't matter since p(B)=1-p(A). By the way, your calculation is wrong: 1 - 0.48625056 = 0.51374944

Comment: I meant 1-0.48383569. Yes, it doesn’t matter for two classes and it must hold that the second probability must be one minus the first one, otherwise they wouldn’t be valid probabilities.